# File upload in codeigniter in shortcut folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

This is not the first time I am doing file upload using CI. However in this particular case I want to upload images or files to **shortcut folder** created at project root. This is what my project root looks like in following image:
[image: hierarchy of document root]

So basically what I had been trying to do is using php **filesystem** function `is_dir('goku')` (**goku is shortcut folder as shown in above image that links to C:\Users\Name\Desktop**) and if **true** then create a sub-folder inside it and insert the image or file in that sub-folder. However I didn't find any way to make the shortcut folder recognize as directory and returns file upload error -`The upload path does not appear to be valid`. Upload works fine on other folder. I know that php is not recognizing the shortcut folder as directory because on running `is_dir('goku')` returns **false**. I have gone through all probable solutions but now again back to where I started. Any helpful hints regarding this is highly appreciated. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the library Codeigniter

[library upload single file and multi file](https://github.com/codeigniters/Uploads)

Easily upload  .

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I hope you properly read my question. I am not trying to do simple file upload. I can already do it using codeigniter library as you stated. What I want is upload the files or images to **shortcut folder** which I made clear in my above question.